# Definition of Abeliants in G.W. Anderson's paper

Tags: algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties

I'm currently reading the paper ["Abeliants and their application to an elementary construction of Jacobians" by G. Anderson.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870802000245)

But I am having problem understanding the definition of the Abeliant rule; especially the part of the family of independent variables $$\{s_i\}_{i=1}^{n} \cup \{t_j\}_{j=1}^{n}.$$

What do the $s's$ and $t's$ really stand for? How are they chosen? And does the definition of the Abeliant depend on the choice of $s$ and $t$?

A simple example (perhaps for $n=2$) illustrating the definition of the Abeliant using the independent variables $s$ and $t$ would be really helpful please.